# So what topics can I ask about here?

Tags: support, off-topic, scope, help-center

There's a help page titled *What topics can I ask about here?* [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The page tells me:

- Not to ask questions that have already been asked
- That I can answer my own question
- That my question must be on topic for the site
- If my question is about recommendations I should ask elsewhere
- If my question is about server configurations I should ask elsewhere
- If my question is a generic PHP question I should ask elsewhere
- Before asking anything elsewhere I should check whether my question is acceptable there
- If there's nowhere to ask my question I could make a new Q&A site for it

That's it. There are eight pieces of advice none of which answer the question posed by the page title: "What topics can I ask about here?"

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the [tour](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tour):

> DevOps Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software engineers working on automated testing, continuous delivery, service integration and monitoring, and building SDLC infrastructure.

We never gone further than this description and the exemple question. That's pretty generic, but roughly this place from its inception was around the "non opinionated" part of IT management.

For everything pure code (CI/CD, config management, infrastructure automation), things are  usually OK. When it comes around "devops culture", the main problem is scoping the question in a narrow enough way to avoid risking a poll. (Early days had plenty of talk around that).

Pure software questions are better asked on StackOverflow, pure system management are better asked on SuperUser, pure organization topics are better asked on the Workplace.

The scope of this site was kinda narrowed on purpose as a place where the question wouldn't really fit the existing sites while still being answerable without being opinion based.

That doesn't give a list of what's allowed and, as far as I know, updating the help center "what's allowed" would require a consensus on this meta first.